# Load ProgressBar while executing ASyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I'm finishing an app, and now I want to add a progressbar or something like the Material Design Loading circle. 
I'm gonna use it while the user login.
The LoginActivity works basically like this: when the user hits the ok button, an ASyncTask gets some data from my API. What I want is to show a progressBar while the ASyncTask makes the inquiry to my API and recieves back the data. 
I've try some libraries and some tutorials but didn't get any results.
This is my LoginActivity:

```
package com.tumta.henrique.teste.view;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tumta.henrique.teste.R;
import com.tumta.henrique.teste.model.ConsultaLogin;
import com.tumta.henrique.teste.util.Connectivity;

import java.util.List;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ConsultaLogin.ConsultaConcluidaLoginListener {

    EditText txtUsuario, txtSenha;
    ActionBar actionbar;
    Button btnOk, btnCancelar;
    private AlertDialog alerta;
    String login, senha;
    Connectivity conn = new Connectivity();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.azul_nav));
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        txtUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_usuario);
        txtSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_senha);
        txtUsuario.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                          KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                    txtSenha.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        txtSenha.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                          KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                    onClickOk(v);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.hide();
        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        btnCancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_cancelar);
        boolean isConnected = conn.isConnected(this);
        if(isConnected == false){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Erro");
            builder.setMessage(R.string.aviso_rede);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.config, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Sair", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alerta = builder.create();
            alerta.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClickOk(View view) {
        try {
            if (txtUsuario.getText().toString().equals("") || txtSenha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Erro");
                builder.setMessage("Preencha todos os campos!");
                builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        login = "";
                        senha = "";
                        txtSenha.getText().clear();
                        txtUsuario.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
                alerta = builder.create();
                alerta.show();
            } else {
                login = txtUsuario.getText().toString();
                senha = txtSenha.getText().toString();
                ConsultaLogin.URL_STRING = "http://186.207.85.205:7001/com.henrique.rest/api/v1/status/login?usu_login="
                        + login + "&usu_senha=" + senha;
                new ConsultaLogin(this).execute();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Erro");
            builder.setMessage("Ocorreu um erro inesperado! \nTente novamente.");
            builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    login = "";
                    senha = "";
                    txtUsuario.getText().clear();
                    txtSenha.getText().clear();
                    txtUsuario.requestFocus();
                }
            });
            alerta = builder.create();
            alerta.show();
        }
    }

    public void onClickCancelar(View view) {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConsultaConcluida(List<String> result) {
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Erro");
            builder.setMessage("Usuario ou Senha Incorreto!");
            builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    login = "";
                    senha = "";
                    txtSenha.getText().clear();
                    txtUsuario.requestFocus();
                }
            });
            alerta = builder.create();
            alerta.show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my ASyncTask:

```
package com.tumta.henrique.teste.model;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Henrique on 16/06/2015.
 */
public class ConsultaLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

    private ConsultaConcluidaLoginListener listener;

    //public static String login, senha;
    public static String URL_STRING = "";


    public ConsultaLogin(ConsultaConcluidaLoginListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            String resultado = ConsultaServidor();
            return InterpretaResultado(resultado);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Erro", "Ocorreu um erro na consulta ao servidor!", e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private List<String> InterpretaResultado(String resultado) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resultado);
        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("login");
        List<String> listaLogin = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonLogin = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (jsonLogin.has("usu_nome")) {
                String nome = jsonLogin.getString("usu_nome");
                listaLogin.add(i, nome);
            } else listaLogin.clear();
        }
        return listaLogin;
    }

    private String ConsultaServidor() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            conn.getResponseCode();

            is = conn.getInputStream();

            Reader reader = null;
            reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            char[] buffer = new char[2048];
            reader.read(buffer);
            return new String(buffer);
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

    public interface ConsultaConcluidaLoginListener {
        void onConsultaConcluida(List<String> result);
    }
}
```

If you need more details, please ask.

Comment: AsyncTask has a cool method called publishProgress which can be used to update the UI while executing. It may be a little overkill for your needs but it's cool nonetheless. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the progressbar to your layout (indeterminate), and toggle visibility on when you initialize the async task. On the callback of the async, toggle the visibility off.

*On request:*

```
login = txtUsuario.getText().toString();
senha = txtSenha.getText().toString();
yourProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ConsultaLogin.URL_STRING = "http://186.207.85.205:7001/com.henrique.rest/api/v1/status/login?usu_login=" + login + "&usu_senha=" + senha;
new ConsultaLogin(this).execute();
```

*On result:*

```
@Override
public void onConsultaConcluida(List<String> result) {
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Erro");
        builder.setMessage("Usuario ou Senha Incorreto!");
        builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                login = "";
                senha = "";
                txtSenha.getText().clear();
                txtUsuario.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        alerta = builder.create();
        alerta.show();
    } else {
        yourProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: And where do I increment the progressbar value? On `doOnBackGround()`?

Comment: You'd use an indeterminate progressbar, meaning it would just spin until the callback was received.

Comment: More on [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) - "In indeterminate mode, the progress bar shows a cyclic animation without an indication of progress. This mode is used by applications when the length of the task is unknown. The indeterminate progress bar can be either a spinning wheel or a horizontal bar."

Comment: actually it worked, I was implementing it wrong, I'll do some  more tests, if I have any issue I let you know..